# One to one chat enable with image, audio and video in quickBlox api

Tags: android

It is possible one to one chat with image, audio and video file between two user in quickBlox api service.

Comment: u can use your own server to doing that work http://im-a-developer-too.blogspot.ca/2014/04/creating-android-xmpp-client-using.html

Comment: No sir we use only QuickBlox api

Comment: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-content-android      it is right

Comment: but above code of link not working.